# Multiple object manipulation in R

Tags: r, function, output, mask, naming

Facing a problem with a function I am trying to set, here. I have the feeling the answer will be pretty simple but I am kinda new to R and stuck,so I would appreciate another opinion.
Essentially what I am trying to do is apply a masking function over several raster files, using a single shape-file as an argument and save my outputs in as many objects as the raster files I am working on. For example:

```
masking <- function(x){
 paste0('x','_45_1',sep='') <- raster::mask(vocc_45_1_rotated,x)
 paste0('x','_45_2',sep='') <- raster::mask(vocc_45_2_rotated,x)
 paste0('x','_45_3',sep='') <- raster::mask(vocc_45_3_rotated,x)
 paste0('x','_85_1',sep='') <- raster::mask(vocc_85_1_rotated,x)
 paste0('x','_85_2',sep='') <- raster::mask(vocc_85_2_rotated,x)
 paste0('x','_85_3',sep='') <- raster::mask(vocc_85_3_new,x)}
```

Unfortunately I keep on getting an

> Error in paste0("x", "_45_1", sep = "") <- raster::mask(vocc_45_1_rotated,  :
>     target of assignment expands to non-language object "

I have seen replies on similar "Error" questions, but nothing that gives me a hint as to what I need to change here.

Comment: LHS cannot be a function. Use `assign` if you want to dynamically assign names to object.

Comment: @AdamQuek _The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign function._ (`fortunes::fortune("assign")`)

Comment: Why don't you use `list()`? I'm afraid that your whole processing pipeline is based on manipulating variable names which isn't the best way in most cases.

Comment: @UweBlock great quote! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with a large number of objects with own names is always tedious and error-prone. Therefore, I suggest to collect all objects of similar structure in a list and to use `lapply()` to manipulate all objects in the list at once. By this, you can easily build up a processing pipeline.

To illustrate this, please, see this example:

```
# create list of objects
vocc <- list(vocc_45_1_rotated, 
             vocc_45_2_rotated, 
             vocc_45_3_rotated, 
             vocc_85_1_rotated, 
             vocc_85_2_rotated,
             vocc_85_3_new)

# name the objects in the list
vocc <- setNames(vocc,
                 c("vocc_45_1", 
                   "vocc_45_2", 
                   "vocc_45_3", 
                   "vocc_85_1", 
                   "vocc_85_2",
                   "vocc_85_3"))

# apply raster::mask function on all objects in list,
# thereby using x as named parameter to function
# The result is again a list
masked_vocc <- lapply(vocc, raster::mask, mask = x)
```

You can retrieve the objects in the list by position

```
masked_vocc[[3]]
```

or by name

```
masked_vocc[["vocc_45_3"]]
```

Comment: Works great..! Thank you for the reply @Uwe, I had the "list() and setNames()" way in my mind but thought that maybe there was another way that would return the raster-brick outputs, individually and named appropriately. Thank you for the comment correction too mate!! xD

Answer (score 0):

#### This should do it, although Im not sure what your `x` represents

But for handling, `x` represents whatever the x above is, `vocc` represents the vocc data object you have statically listed in your example above, `env` represents the environment in which to assign the output.

We create the new objects name by forcing the `vocc` input object to a quoted string (see: ?deparse and ?substitute or see below on how this works). Then we substitute everything from the string that is a letter, but not an underscore, so that we can get the unique `_42_1` or whatever that is used to identify your objects individually. Reference the `.GlobalEnv` so that the function assigns its return to the top-level env, rather than the functions environment, and evaluate the `raster::` function inside the assignment. See `assign` for more details.

```
deparse(substitute(mtcars))
[1] "mtcars"

masking <- function(x,vocc = NULL, env = .GlobalEnv){
    name_var <- deparse(substitute(vocc))
    n_parts <- gsub('[a-z]|(?=_)','',name_var, perl = TRUE)
    new_name <- sprintf('x%s', n_parts)
    assign(new_name, raster::mask(vocc, x), envir = env)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Carl. I will check the deparse, substitute and assign functions in depth, as I have noticed you need to be kinda cautious when "parameterizing", and get back to you when I make it work this way too. Cheers !